# How to connect in sql management studio 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have installed the Sql server 2008 express edition with tools. After Installing sql server 2008 and sql server management studio. When i open the sql management studio it shows a window, Connect to server. Here I got already filled boxes like that:

```
Server type: Database Engine

Sever name: (local)

Authentication: Windows Authentication
```

When i click on the Connect button it displays an error message box, and nothing will be created. What can i do. Would someone help me to fix it.

Comment: Try to choose SQL Server authentification type method, and log in with the SA account you have defined during SQL Server install

Answer (score 0):

Open run--> CMD
execute this code : `NET START MSSQLSERVER` for default instance and `NET START MSSQL$<INSTANCENAME>` for named instance.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with user2196728, you should be able to connect using the SA account specified during installation. At that point you should be able to setup an account using your domain account (windows authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that this is turned to on (2008R2):

1. Click on the Start Menu.
2. Go to the folder `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2`
3. Click on the folder `Configuration Tools`
4. Launch `SQL Server Configuration Manager`
5. When that loads, on the far left menu, click on `SQL Server Services`
6. You should see at least three items on the right window, probably `SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)`, `SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS)`, and `SQL Server Browser`.  Right click on `SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)` and click Start (if it's highlighted out, that means it's running).

Then try logging into `local` again using `Windows Authentication`.